# MIPS ASM Homework - Arrays and while loops

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, while-loop, mips

First, let me say this...I don't want anyone to just give me an answer...I'd like to be pointed in the right direction!

I have an array of integers in this program....for instance:

```
numbers:
     .word  17
     .word -50
     .word   1
     .word -999
```

I have a while loop that runs through them and prints each one on a new line.  That works fine.  (-999 is the terminating number, and is not included in the printout)

I also need to print them in the reverse order.  I know that I could use a loop to count the number of elements and then have another loop that starts at the last address and goes backwards....this seems to be inefficient, though.

Is there some way to find the address of the last element in an array without doing a loop first?  If not, I can do it this way I mentioned, just want to make sure I'm being as efficient as I can in the program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you had a length, you could jump right there, but if the array end is only indicated by -999, you have the right idea about scanning for it and going backwards from there.

Comment: If you have no more information (like last element address) then no.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to do any assembly tricks you want, you could do something like

```
numbers:
 .word  17
 .word -50
 .word   1
last:
 .word -999
```

and use code like this pseudo code

```
for (ptr = last; ptr != numbers; ) print(*--ptr);
```

In other words, put a label and the end of the array and walk backwards until you hit the beginning of the array, using a pointer comparison instead of looking for the terminator (-999).

Or, to avoid changing you code too much, how about

```
 .word -999
numbers:
 .word  17
 .word -50
 .word   1
last:
 .word -999
```

and walk backward until you find the -999?

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I will definitely put that in my list of tricks, however, since this is a homework assignment, and they will be adding the numbers: array to my file to run the different tests, I don't have any control over that part of it.

Comment: You don't have to change the data structure presented, but you still can do this trick: `numbers:
    .word  17
    .word -50
    .word   1
    .word -999

last:
 .word -999` And btw Richard Pennington, you don't need that leading `.word -999` since you have the `numbers` label.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, even though its on a new label, it will still be in the next spot in memory after the last word in numbers: ?  That way, I can just count backwards from that label address?